# How do i select them separately in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two a tags and I want to create two separate click functions because they behave different.

```
<div class="select-big">
    <div class="select-holder">
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#" class="trigger right"></a>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s2">Restaurant</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-s icon-s1" href="#">Grocery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s2">Pizza Delivery</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select-holder select-holder2">
        <div class="button">
            <div id="one1" class="left number_changer"></div>
            <p id="count_of_stations" class="text left">Number Of Stations</p>
            <a href="#" class="trigger right"></a>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">​
```

currently i have this that selects both

```
$('.select-big ul li a').click(function () {
```

Comment: *How* do they behave differently?  Do they do the same thing just relative to their own elements, or completely different actions?

Comment: they behave differently based on the url constructed for example this line

  $("#main_content").load("function.php?type="+type+"piz&count=5", successCallback );

the type piz is the inserted if the user selects the top dropdown and the count 5 is constructed based on the number selecter on the bottom. So i dont know what the user is selecting so I dont want this to happen

$("#main_content").load("function.php?type="+type+"5&count=piz", successCallback );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give them unique IDs

```
<li><a id="someID" href="#" class="icon-s icon-s2">Restaurant</a></li>  
<li><a id="someOtherID" class="icon-s icon-s1" href="#">Grocery</a></li>
<li><a id="someDifferentID" href="#" class="icon-s icon-s2">Pizza Delivery</a></li>
```

jQuery

```
$('#someID').click(function() {
    //  do something
});

$('#someotherID').click(function() {
    //  do something else
});
```

or select them by index:

```
$('.select-big ul li a:eq(0)').click(function() {
    //  do something
});

$('.select-big ul li a:eq(1)').click(function() {
    //  do something else
});
```

or traverse from one to the next (if they are adjascent).

```
$('.select-big ul li a:eq(0)').click(function() {
    //  do something
})
  .next().click(function() {
    //  do something else
});
```